# How to extract the react and react-dom from the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reasons, we need to reduce the codebase size.
We need to split out `react`, `react-dom` components from our project.
Currently, all the stuffs are bundled into `app.js` through webpack.

How could we keep using these imports by splitting them out from the `app.js` and load them explicitly?

e.g:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/react-dom.js"></script>


    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

## Original

```
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/app.js"></script>
```

## Expect result

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://~/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using Webpack to build the bundle? If so, you can look into code splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack `externals` option is what you're looking for.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

You can keep all of your imports in the code, but the dependency will be provided by you (through script tags), instead of webpack.

Comment: will give it a try. Will that cause a lot of webpack warnings or typescript warning?

Comment: It shouldn't cause webpack warnings, seeing as how it's a webpack feature. Idk about typescript.